# Let a webform know fropm which page are users coming from

Tags: 7, webforms

I am developing a Drupal 7 site, with an Omega sub-theme, panels, and views. On every product page, I have a link to a webform. I need the webform to know from which page the customer is coming from.

Is there a specific Drupal way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use the Prepopulate module, if you are trying to pre-fill the webform with arguments from the URL.

There are probably several ways how to do this, but the first thing which came to my mind was to add a view block which can be shown on your originating content type and that will be used to create the link with the node ID for your webform to process.

> [image: screenshot]

This is very simple with a view, where you only need to add two fields and then place the block in a theme region. The first field you need is the *Content: Nid* field and exclude it from the display. Then you will add *Global: Custom text* and write the form URL (it must be configured when creating the webform), the field name as key and the *[nid]* token as the value in the URL.

[image: screenshot]

*field_form_house_er* is a webform field which has been set to prepopulate from the URL.

A contextual filter must be added to the view to pass the node ID to the block using the *Content ID from URL* option from *Provide default value*.

[image: screenshot]

After saving the view, it can be placed in a theme region. It will create the link every time a node is viewed.
You will probably need different webforms for different content types. With generic settings, this setup will work with any content type if you have set up the webform to allow any content type to be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Iain - it sounds very straightforward. I will give it a go tonight.

Answer (score 1):

On you link display something like this :

```
$current_path = current_path();
$current_path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($current_path);    
print url('my-webform', array('query' => array('from' => $current_path_alias )));
```

If you are on content/mynode, the link will display my-webform?from=content/mynode.
If you want just the unaliased path skip the use of `dupal_get_path_alias()`

```
$current_path = current_path(); 
print url('my-webform', array('query' => array('from' => $current_path)));
```

If you are on node/18, the link will display my-webform?from=node/18.